# Python 2.7: Access database table and CSV file comparison

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I need to compare `.accdb` file with `.csv` file.

Both file files having same type of records with count mismatch. So I want to display those records which are in uncommon and store it into new text file separeted with `;` with the column header.

**.accdb**:

```
ID  Name
1   Mak
2   Smith
3   Jack
```

**.csv File**:

```
ID  Name
1   Mak
2   Smith
3   Jack
4   Johnson
5   Mike
```

**Expected .txt file**:

```
ID;  Name
4;   Johnson
5;  Mike
```

**My try**:

```
import pyodbc

CSVfile = 'E:\Python\AccessCSVFiles\EMP.csv'
TEXTfile = 'E:\Python\AccessCSVFiles\EMP_UPDATES.txt'

conn_string = r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=E:\Python\AccessCSVFiles\EMP.accdb;'
con = pyodbc.connect(conn_string)
cur = con.cursor()

SQLQuery = 'SELECT * FROM EMP;'
rows = cur.execute(SQLQuery).fetchall()
records = [tuple(map(str,record)) for record in rows]

accessfile = set(records)

with open(CSVfile) as a:
    first_line = a.readline()
    with open(TEXTfile, 'w') as result:
        result.write(first_line)
        for line in a:
            if line not in accessfile:
                print line
```

But getting all 5 records separated with `,` in the text file `EMP_UPDATES.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

use [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) to read `CSV`:

```
import csv
with open(CSVfile) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    csv_data = {(row['ID'], row['Name']) for row in reader}  # generates set
```

If only `CSV` is expected to contain missing data:

```
diff = sorted(csv_data.difference(accessfile))  # Generated Sorted list with values missing
                                                # in accessfile
```

To write into new file:

```
with open(TEXTfile, 'w') as result:
    for missing in diff:
        result.write(";".join(missing))
```